# Import Failure - Role With Id Does Not Exist

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I am getting an import error in a specific environment with a managed CRM 2011 solution.  The solution has been imported before into many other environments, but the one in particular where it is failing is throwing the following error:

```
Dependency Calculation
role With Id = 9e2d2d9b-645f-409f-b31d-3a9c39fcc340 Does Not Exist
```

I am a bit confused about this.  I searched within the solution XML and was not able to find any reference to this particular GUID of 9e2d2d9b-645f-409f-b31d-3a9c39fcc340.  I cannot really find it in SQL either, just wandering through the different tables, but perhaps I do not know exactly where to look there.

I have tried importing the solution multiple times.  As a desperation effort, I tried renaming all of the security roles in the destination environment prior to importing, but this did not help.

1. Where is this reference to a security role actually stored?  Is this something that is supposed to be within my solution--which my existing CRM deployment is expecting me to import?
2. How do I fix the problem so that I am able to import this solution?

Comment: Have you tried looking for the security role in a previously deployed environment?

Comment: I could be looking in the wrong place.  I am looking under the `dbo.RoleBase` table to check each instance.  I did not see a reference to that GUID anywhere (searching on `WHERE [RoleId] = '9e2d2d9b-645f-409f-b31d-3a9c39fcc340'`).  I just checked the instances where the solution has already successfully been installed (I think that is what you were suggesting).

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering if one of the other orgs that had successfully imported the solution, would have the Role Id in it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the code we used to fix the issue.  We had to run two different scripts.  Script A we had to run a total of four times.  Run it once, attempt the import, and then consult the log to find the role that is causing the problem--if you receive another error for another role.

To run script A, you must use a valid `RoleTemplateId` from your database.  We just picked a random one.  It should not matter precisely which one you use, because you will erase that data element with script B.

After all of the roles are fixed, we got a different error (complaining something about the `RoleTemplateId` was already related to a role), and had to run script B.  That removes the `RoleTemplateId` from multiple different roles and sets it to `NULL`.

**Script A:**

```
insert into RoleBaseIds(RoleId)
values ('WXYZ74FA-7EA3-452B-ACDD-A491E6821234')

insert into RoleBase(RoleId
    ,RoleTemplateId
    ,OrganizationId
    ,Name
    ,BusinessUnitId
    ,CreatedOn
    ,ModifiedOn
    ,CreatedBy
    )
values ('WXYZ74FA-7EA3-452B-ACDD-A491E6821234'
    ,'ABCD89FF-7C35-4D69-9900-999C3F605678'
    ,(select organizationid from Organization)
    ,'ROLE IMPORT FIX'
    ,(select BusinessUnitID from BusinessUnit where ParentBusinessUnitId is null)
    ,GETDATE()
    ,GETDATE()
    ,null       
    )
```

**Script B:**

```
update RoleBase
set RoleTemplateId = NULL
where RoleTemplateID='ABCD89FF-7C35-4D69-9900-999C3F605678'
```

Answer (score 1):

Perfect solution, worked for me! My only comment would be the error in Script B: it shouldn't clear the template IDs of all roles for the given template, only the template ID of the newly created "fix" role, as follows:

```
update RoleBase
set RoleTemplateId = NULL
where RoleID='WXYZ74FA-7EA3-452B-ACDD-A491E6821234'
```

I would've gladly put this in a comment to the answer, but not enough rep as of now.